# How to get user creation timestamp in RDS Postgres 9.3.1/9.3.2/9.3.3

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, amazon-redshift, postgresql-9.3

I am able to get user creation timestamp in Amazon Redshift like below:

```
redshiftpocdb6=# select username,recordtime,valuntil from stl_userlog where username = 'u002';
                      username                      |         recordtime         |           valuntil
----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+------------------------------
 u002                                               | 2014-07-23 14:36:11.314898 | 294277-01-09 04:00:54.775807
(1 row)
```

How to get the same info in RDS Postgres 9.3.3? This above table is not existing.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no automatic provision** for that in PostgreSQL. You need to add a column with default value per table yourself:

```
ALTER TABLE stl_userlog ADD column created_at timestamp DEFAULT now()
```

Doesn't work for rows that are already there. That ship has sailed ...